# Request to spotify and get songs, .... But Its Slow

Tags: c#, .net, spotify

I wrote this method for request to spotify api and get songs, ... but its slow.

> _client injected in constructor, the type is HttpClient

```
//constructor
public SpotifyApi()
{
   _client = new HttpClient()
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION_URL)
    };

    authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CLIENT_ID + ":" + CLIENT_SECRET));
}

//method
public async Task<object> GetSearchAsync(spotifyFilter filter)
{
     var requestAuthorization = RequestAuthorization();
     if (requestAuthorization.access_token == null)
         throw new Exception(ResultCode.badRequest);

     _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
     _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(requestAuthorization.token_type, requestAuthorization.access_token);

     var uri = new Uri(BASE_URL + "?" + ObjToQueryString(filter));

     HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync(uri);
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
         if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
             throw new Exception(ResultCode.unauthorized);

         if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
             throw new Exception(ResultCode.forbidden);

         if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests)
             throw new Exception(ResultCode.badRequest, "TooManyRequests");
     }

     var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

     var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(responseBody);

     return result;
 }
```

1. Did I make anything wrong or not ?
2. How can make it this method better ?

Comment: how slow is it?

Comment: Little hint -> `await AnyAsyncMethodCall().ConfigureAwait(false);` should help a lot

Comment: @chetan not soo fast and not too slow
but is slow than you think